# Probability Question about the sum of two random uniform variables module

Tags: probability, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

assume two random uniform independent variables X,Y~Unif([N]) prove that the modulo of the sum:
((
X
+
Y
)
modulo N) follows a uniform distribution on the set
{0,1,…,N−1}

i need to general proof for any N that belongs to Z

i tried:
defining another variable Z = (x+y)ModuleN
and then saying P(Z=z)=P((x+y)ModuleN = z)

and then i thought of using the fact that they are independent

maybe something like for every z P(Z=z)= sum for every z P(x=i)*P(y=n-i)moduleN

Comment: What is the ‘mod’?

Comment: From the context I guess it's mod N

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  For small $N$, there should be no problem computing this by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary $k \in \left\{0, 1, ..., N-1\right\}$. For any $X$ value in $\left\{0, 1, ..., N-1\right\}$, there is exactly one $Y$ value in $\left\{0, 1, ..., N-1\right\}$ such that $X+Y \equiv k \pmod{N}$.

Specifically, this value [is](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/3613/3613-l07.pdf): $\,\,k - X \pmod{N}$.

Therefore the following cardinality is constant and is equal to $N$:

$$\left|\left\{\left(X,Y\right) \in \left\{0, 1, ..., N-1\right\}^2 : X+Y \equiv k \pmod{N}\right\}\right| \, = \, N$$

Because our choice of $k$ was arbitrary, this implies that the distribution you describe is uniform.